# Extract float from string extracted from html

Tags: python, html

I am trying to extract data from a simple html page that takes temperature reading from arduino I have managed to get to the point where I get the string with the temperature reading which is:

> 'Temperature in Celsius: \r\n 23.20\r\n*C'

but I cannot work out how to extract the temperature float from the string, any suggestions? please bear in mind that the resulting temperature changes as the arduino take live reading...

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://192.168.1.103:180')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
extract = tree.xpath('/html/body/h3[1]/text()')
print extract
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to apply a regular expression:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = 'Temperature in Celsius: \r\n 23.20\r\n*C'

In [3]: re.search(r"\d+\.\d+", s).group(0)
Out[3]: '23.20'
```

where `\d+` matches one or more consecutive digits, `\.` is a literal dot.

Or, you can split by `:` and "strip" the unneeded part:

```
In [4]: s.split(":")[-1].strip(" \r\n*C")
Out[4]: '23.20'
```

Note that `xpath()` method in lxml returns a *list*, don't forget to get the desired string from it.